# assign bash variable to make variable inside recipe

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is there a way to capture the bash variable into a make variable inside the recipe. I am trying somethign like this:

```
all:
    VER=$$(cat file.txt) && echo This is $${VER} \
    foo=$${VER}
    echo Hey $$(foo) !
```

I get an error :

```
VER=$(cat file.txt) && echo This is ${VER} \
foo=${VER}
This is 100 foo=100
echo Hey $(foo) !
/bin/sh: 1: foo: not found
Hey !
```

I think the `VER` bash variable is captured correctly but I would like to capture it to a make variable in the recipe?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you really shouldn't do this and it's close to being not possible.  We could help you much more if you told us what you're actually trying to do... this feels like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

GNU make (but not other versions of make) do have a way that this is possible, with some caveats.  However, I reiterate that this is a very bad idea and you shouldn't do it.  Nevertheless, this will work:

```
all:
        $(eval VER := $$(shell cat file.txt))
        echo This is $(VER)
```

One caveat is that this happens *before* any other part of your recipe is run.  So for example, this won't work:

```
all: clean
        echo hello > file.txt
        $(eval VER := $$(shell cat file.txt))
        echo This is $(VER)

clean: ; rm -f file.txt
```

The `eval` is invoked before any part of the recipe is started.

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense. But as you pointed out, `eval` will run at the beginning, and I wanted to run it sequentially, hence the attempt to do what I am doing, and its likely a wrong way. I will try to write out a detailed question.